# Taking Away part of an Object

Tags: java, element

So I know that you can add an object in java to something through something like this:

```
topPanel.add(something);
```

However, how would I do this with taking something out of the topPanel. Something that would basically mean the following:

```
topPanel.takeAway(winCounter);
```

Is there a way to do this, and what is the proper syntax of it?

Comment: topPanel.remove(something); ?

Comment: What kind of class is `topPanel` an instance of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the remove() method

```
  topPanel.remove(winCounter);
```

Comment: Assuming that `topPanel` is some kind of `Collection`, I take it?

Comment: I'm assuming topPanel is a subclass of java.awt.Container, eg. a JPanel

Answer (score 0):

The object will have to contain a *collection* and some *add* and *remove* methods. Here's a basic example:

```
public class Parent {
  List children = new ArrayList();

  public void add(Node node) {
   items.add(node);
  }

  public void remove(Node node) {
   items.remove(node);
  }
}
```